# ...crisis where you'll freak out... -> why Where?

Tags: word-usage

> You'll certainly have some kind of crisis **where** you'll freak out about how important something is to you.

Can I replace Where with That or Which? If not, why I couldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**that** and **which** are relative pronouns. They generally act as the subject of the second part of the sentence:

> I know the man **that** wrote this book

In this example, **that** is a relative pronoun referring to **the man**, and acting as the subject of the second clause.

In your sentence, **you** is the subject of the sentence, so you can't use a relative pronoun in the sentence as it stands. You could alter the sentence to make it so that **that**, referring to the crisis, is the subject:

> You'll certainly have some kind of crisis **that** will freak you out about how important something is to you.

In your sentence, **where** is a relative adverb (see [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/where)). Its meaning is that the first clause defines a place or situation which the second clause describes.

**that** and **which** cannot be used as a relative adverb.

**which** can be used [with a preposition **in**, **at**, **for**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/which) as a relative pronoun to refer to something that isn't the subject of the second clause:

> it was a crisis **for which** he was totally unprepared

You could therefore write your sentence like this:

> You'll certainly have some kind of crisis **in which** you'll freak out about how important something is to you.