# "Where" : is there a meal where you eat the same thing every day? What?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, parsing

I came across this question where "where" is used as the pronoun of place in time.

I don't understand the function

> Is there a meal **where** you eat the same thing every day? what?

Comment: I'd prefer "at which" but it's the same as [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/193827/crisis-where-youll-freak-out-why-where) - where does not always refer to a physical place, but can refer to a situation or time.

Comment: English speakers have undersood the space-time continuum since long before Einstein. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+meal+where%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=582337527&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKniszFfdk8AgnROwpXW2M2dniCE6A:1699986337747&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj6aLOjsSCAxXQg4kEHYXAAdAQ0pQJKAV6BAgDEAg&biw=1323&bih=684&dpr=1

Comment: We don't usually say *I had an egg **at** breakfast* (or *I have the same thing at dinner every day*). We say *I had an egg **for** breakfast,* and that prepositional adverbial usage transforms into *Is there a meal **which** you eat the same thing **for** every day?* Horses for courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A meal" in the cited context would normally be one of *breakfast, lunch, dinner, tea* (a *type* of meal that you might have every day). For example, *Do you always eat porridge for breakfast?*

The (metaphoric) prepositional element could be overtly "position-based" *(**where**),* or it could be "time-based" *(**when**)*. Some people may prefer ***at which*** (which is essentially "positional", but is very common in "temporal" references). It's a stylistic choice.

It's a less *likely* choice, but there's nothing particularly unusual (certainly nothing "syntactically incorrect") about using a *container* metaphorical reference here: *Is there a meal **in which** you always have a glass of of water with your food?*

The "literal" meaning of the specific "relativizer" (whatever you want to call such elements) is irrelevant in such contexts. It's just that *syntactically*, we need something there. It could just as well be an "adverb of purpose / content":-

> *Is there a meal **for which** you eat the same thing every day?*

Comment: Yeah, sure, it's grammatical but who says that??

Comment: How often does anyone ever ask anything like OP's question? It's [the only example of it's kind](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Is+there+a+meal+where%22) in Google Books. I just leafed through the couple of dozen matches for "**Is there a meal**", and there's nothing else of that general type. As I said, we just need something there for *syntactic* reasons, and if you don't like any of my suggestions above, that doesn't really mean anything. There is no "uniquely and unquestionably correct" version, and I have no problem with any of them.

Comment: I said you **says** that? Not who writes that...Click on Tim's link.

Comment: I think you're just nitpicking for the sake of it. Forget it.

Comment: Your explanations are fine but hard for learners to understand....

Comment: 'There is enormous satisfaction in sitting down to a meal where you know where every element has come from'. The Irish Times

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well, there it is. Not shite at all. But I guess I am still the "bad guy".

Comment: @Lambie - I think I might prefer 'when' for that type of sentence, but either would do, surely.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: But imho ***where*** there does (or at least *could*) modify the action *sitting down to a meal,* not the meal itself. Me, I'd have no problem with unambiguously *sitting down to a meal **that** you know where every element has come from!*